# Block User Info Prestashop

Tags: header, block, prestashop-1.6, info

Good morning! How can I edit Block User Info from Prestashop? I have a default-template with log in, my account, checkbox, log in and compare. I want to delete some fields and edit others. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: With both languages is better (y)

Comment: I didnt know it... thanks (y)